# Add a new palette/swatch .gpl file to Inkscape when installed as a snap

Tags: snap, inkscape

I have installed Inkscape 0.92.4 on Ubuntu 18.04 as a snap from the official Ubuntu software installer snap store.

I want to add a new .gpl palette to Inkscape so that it's available in all my projects like other system palettes. This is normally achieved by adding the .gpl file to the palettes folder in the Inkscape install but this isn't possible as snaps are installed with a read only file system. I've have tried creating the palette folder in all the places the non-snap version of Inkscape would look (/usr/share/inkscape/palettes etc...) and in various places in ~/snap/inkscape/.... but no luck. Where should I put my new .gpl palette file?

Comment: I think that putting the file in `~/.local/share/inkscape/palettes/` may work, assuming that Inkscape reads in this folder as most programs do.

Comment: I just tried it out. I can't get palettes in that folder to show in Inkscape, I tried with both Snap and non-Snap versions. Thanks @AaronFranke for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is to place the palette file in `~/.config/inkscape/palettes/`.

The location is actually given in Inkscape. In the menu, go Edit -> Preferences, then the `System` item on the left. This page will show the correct location for all sorts of things, including palette files. I have confirmed this is correct for both the snap version and the normal version on Inkscape.

Answer (score 1):

I had to put it in `~/snap/inkscape/4693/palettes/` directory. The number `4693` may be different for you, you'll have to change accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

#### via terminal :)

Say we save our *paletteName.gpl* file to the Desktop

1. Open terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T)
2. Paste the code below into the terminal

```
    cd Desktop/
    mv paletteName.gpl ~/.config/inkscape/palettes/
```